# Symfony2, the UniqueEntity constraint message is not being translated

Tags: php, symfony, translation

I added a `UniqueEntity` constraint to my entity following the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html). The constraint is working fine, I get the default error message:

> This value is already used.

When I replace the message with a translation key like `unique_entity.message` and add this key in the `validators.en.yml` (I successfully added other asserts translations to that file), the error message is the translation key itself instead of the translated message.

I tried clearing the cache, it didn't work. I tried checking the source code of the constraints files, but I am lost in the many files, from what I could find, it should work.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: do you have `translator` enabled? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#book-translation-configuration Also, include your `validation.yml` code in the question, please.

Comment: Are you trying to translate the validation message inside a form? If yes ... the translation process itself takes place there usually.

Comment: @carrie kendall The translator is enabled, like I said, I have other validators translations that are working in that same file. It seems that the problem occurs only with this UniqueEntity, all other asserts from the Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints namespace are working.

Comment: @nifr The validation is indeed in a form validation: $form->isValid(), what should be different from another form to make UniqueEntity translations work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason, I was using a function get get the list of errors to encode them in json to use with an ajax form, this is the function:

```
private function getFormErrorMessages(Form $form)
{
    $errors = array();

    foreach ($form->getErrors() as $key => $error) {
        $template = $error->getMessageTemplate();
        $parameters = $error->getMessageParameters();

        $error = $template;

        foreach ($parameters as $var => $value) {
            $error = str_replace($var, $value, $template);
        }

        $errors[] = array(
            'error' => $error,
            'template' => $template,
            'parameters' => $parameters,
        );
    }

    if ($form->count()) {
        foreach ($form as $child) {
            if (!$child->isValid()) {
                $errors = array_merge($errors, $this->getFormErrorMessages($child));
            }
        }
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

Well, it happens that this function gets the translated normal errors (from Asserts), but not the UniqueEntity ones. Which appears to be translated during the view creation, maybe.

So instead of getting the list of errors, I just returned the new rendered form containing the errors in json and replaced the old one with it and all the errors are translated like they should.